# SQL Aggregation keeping non aggregated columns from separate tables in VB.NET

Tags: sql

I am utilizing VB.NET to pull data from a database via an SQLDataAdapter, place it into a DataSet, and then display it in a DataGridView. This all works fine but I need to Group the data by the EquipmentName column and then display only the Max StateChangeID of the group while still display the non-aggregated fields as well (EquipmentStateName etc...). I also know how to create the query that selects just EquipmentName and StateChangeID wile grouping and aggregating but getting the data from both is stumping me.

Initially ask this as a VB.NET question thinking there may be a way to pull two seperate querys and then combine them but I never could figure that out. I was advised to amend the question to focus on SQL so I have.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim myCconnectionString As String = "Server=SCDCMMSSQL02;Database=CMMS_PROD;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
        Dim mySqlAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim myDS As New DataSet



        myConnection = New SqlConnection(myCconnectionString)

        myConnection.Open()

        mySqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("        
        SELECT     
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.EquipmentStateChangeID,
        RTP.vwt_Equipment.EquipmentName,
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentState.EquipmentStateName,
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.Comments,
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.LastUpdatedBy,
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.LastUpdated

        FROM        
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        RTP.vwt_EquipmentState 
        ON RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.EquipmentStateID = RTP.vwt_EquipmentState.EquipmentStateID 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        RTP.vwt_Equipment 
        ON RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.EquipmentID = RTP.vwt_Equipment.EquipmentID

        WHERE       
        (RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.CreatedDate > DATEADD(WEEK,-4,GETDATE()) )
        AND
        (RTP.vwt_EquipmentStateChange.Comments NOT LIKE '%Cluster%')

        ORDER BY    
        RTP.vwt_Equipment.EquipmentName ASC", myConnection)

        'Reading from DB to DataSet and displaying by data grid
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDS, "EXEC")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = myDS
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "EXEC"

        myConnection.Close()
        myConnection.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this. Should I do it within the initial SQL (Which I cant figure out). Should I manipulate it while it is in the DataSet. Should I attempt accomplish the Group By / Aggregation using LINQ (Which I would need to learn and would).

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: You should absolutely do it in SQL if you possibly can because it will be far more efficient than manipulating the data in-app. You should change the question to specifically ask about the SQL because the VB part is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you  for the advice, I will edit my post now. Thanks!